# How to create Linq to Sql with left join, aggregate, and where clause

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Does anyone know how to convert this query to LINQ to SQL?

```
SELECT posts.*, count(COMMENTS.*) AS comment_count FROM POSTS
LEFT JOIN COMMENTS on POSTS.id = COMMENTS.post_id
WHERE comments.date IS NULL OR comments.date >= [NOW]
GROUP BY posts.id
ORDER BY comment_count DESC
```

It's simple enough in SQL, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around linq to sql. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You want something like this:

```
var query =
    from p in POSTS
    join c in COMMENTS on p.id equals c.post_id into cs
    group new
    {
        Post = p,
        Comments = cs
            .Where(c1 => c1.date >= DateTime.Now)
            .Count(),
    } by p.id;
```

Comment: Can you explain the query a bit?  I don't see how this does a left join =/

Comment: @gogogom3 The key part is the `into cs`. If that were left out the query would be a full join, but with the `into` it produces a sequence of values - the `cs` variable - that are all the associated comments (zero or more) associated with each post. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion you can always use this great tool

http://www.sqltolinq.com/

to help with conversion